# Trying to reactively update chart data, however, the chart does not reflect the changes. Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Sadly, I am facing some Vue.js reactivity issues yet again. Currently my code renders the chart once on `mounted()` and then it re-renders the chart every time the data updates thanks to a watcher. This does work (aside from the fact that I'm not sure how to remove the previously rendered charts), however, I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing the update considering I am using Vue. Having the already rendered chart update on data update seems like a better option to me instead of rendering a whole new chart and deleting the old one.

I tried changing the data using `this.data = the new data`, however, I know that this will not make the object reactive. I also tried using this.$set as is explained here - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html , however, I am not achieving anything with it. I might not be using it correctly though. I also tried changing just one property of the object which also wasn't affecting the chart.

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <button @click="updateChart()">X</button>
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            data: {
                labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
                }],
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateChart(){
            this.data = {
                labels: ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'EYOOOOOOOOOOOOOO',
                    data: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
                }],
            }
            /*this.$set(this.data, {
                labels: ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Please Work',
                    data: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
                }],
            }))*/
            /*this.$set(this.data, 'labels', ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red'])*/
        },
        renderChart(data, options){
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: data,
                options: options
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
    },
    watch: {
        data: function() {
            this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you trying to get `updateChart` method to work, or the watcher for `data` to work? If `updateChart` is working, why not call `renderChart` after making the updates in `updateChart`? Also you may need to use `{ deep: true }` for the watcher for `data`: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch

Answer (score 0):

From: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

> Sometimes you may want to assign a number of properties to an existing
> object, for example using Object.assign() or _.extend(). However, new
> properties added to the object will not trigger changes. In such
> cases, create a fresh object with properties from both the original
> object and the mixin object:

Try updating your `this.data` by doing this:

```js
this.data = Object.assign({}, {
                labels: ['Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red', 'Red'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Please Work',
                    data: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
                }],
            })
```

Comment: Well my console log indicates that the data has been updated, however, my chart doesn't show any changes. Any clue as to why?

Comment: What library are you using to render your chart? It sounds like the issues lies in `renderChart`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a **deep watcher** on data.

```
{
  watch: { 
    data: {
      handler: function(value) {
        this.renderChart(this.data, this.options)
      },
      deep: true,
    }
  }
}
```

BTW it is confusing to have a `data` property called `data`...  I suggest changing it to `chartData`.

In `Vue`, only the top level object properties will trigger reactive changes. `deep` will cause nested objects (in your case `labels` and `datasets`) to also trigger an update. Most cases do not need deep, so to eliminate the overhead you need to add it if you want it.

Make sure you do not add any new properties to an existing data object without going through `Vue.set`.  That is the next most common issue when the UI does not update to data changes.

Comment: Can you briefly explain what does this deep watcher do?

Comment: In Vue, only the top level properties on an object will trigger reactivity.  `Deep` will cause nested objects (labels/datasets) to also trigger an update.  Most cases do not need deep, so to eliminate the overhead you need to add it if you want it.